# How convert a date from dd-mm-yy to mm-dd-yy

Tags: php, date

How convert a date from `dd-mm-yy` to `mm-dd-yy`

below is my code

```
<?
$date= date('d-m-y');
echo date('m-d-Y',strtotime($date));
?>
```

but the result is : `09-10-2001`

i need `09-01-2010`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$input = 'dd-mm-yy';
$a = explode('-',$input);
$result = $a[1].'-'.$a[0].'-'.$a[2];
```

Comment: $old_date = date($date);
    $old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
    $new_date = date('d-m-Y', $old_date_timestamp);

Answer (score 8):

This won't work:

```
date('m-d-y', strtotime($the_original_date));
```

If you have PHP 5.3, you can do:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', '09-10-01');
$new_date = $date->format('m-d-Y');
```

Otherwise:

```
$parts = explode('-', $original_date);
$new_date = $parts[1] . '-' . $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[2];
```

Comment: This will fail in certain situations because strtotime recognizes US English dates. 03-01-10 will be interpreted as March 1, 2010 not January 3, 2010.

Comment: this is my code 
<?
$date= date('d-m-y');

echo date('m-d-Y',strtotime($date));
but the result is: 09-10-2001
i need 09-01-2010

thanks for your reply

Comment: Updated answer because it was entirely wrong. Thanks @stillstanding.

Answer (score 0):

try this `date("m-d-y", {your date variable})`

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always like above, this should work:

```
$pieces = explode("-", $yourTimestring);
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$pieces[1], $pieces[0], $pieces[2]);
$newDateStr = date("m-d-y", $timestamp);
```

**Edit:** True, just saw the answer from "codaddict" and yeah, if i alredy split it up you could also concatenate it directly ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`sscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) function if you dont have PHP 5.3 available and make use of the argument swapping option:

```
$theDate = '01-02-03';
print join(sscanf($theDate, '%2$2s-%1$2s-%3$2s'), '-');
# output: 02-01-03
```

`sscanf` basically parses the provided string in an array based on the provided format, swapping the first matched argument (the day) with the second (the month), leaving the third one (year) untouched and then this array is joined again with the `-` as separator.